# Converting ipydatagrid Jupyter Notebook widget to PyQt widget readable by lauout.addWidget() method

Tags: python, pyqt, widget, spreadsheet

**Question.**
How can I embed ipydatagrid(or similar) editable spreadsheet widget in PyQt5? I am not interested in creating spreadsheets from basic elements available in PyQt.
So I am interested in creating widget readable by layout.addWidget() method out of Jupyter Notebook widget.
It would be good to see working baby example.

**My attempt.**
I was trying to create window with an interactive editable spreadsheet using ipydatagrid. So I tried adding this widget by addwidget(). I received an error message that tells that my sheet1 widget has a wrong type. So how can I convert it in type readable by PyQt5?
I was able to use this widget in Jupyter notebook without PyQt.

**My research.**
I wasn't able to find any information about using ipydatagrid or ipysheet widgets in PyQt.
My question had been marked as a duplicate to question below.

[Pyqt5/Pyside application with Ipywidgets and Interactive figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58233826/pyqt5-pyside-application-with-ipywidgets-and-interactive-figures)

This question only indicates an direction of further research of this matter. There is told that Voila can do the trick. This answer doesn't satisfy me, because it is too abstract.

**My Code.**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        # create menu
        menubar = QMenuBar()
        layout.addWidget(menubar, 0, 0)
        import pandas as pd
        from ipydatagrid import DataGrid
        d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
        sheet1=DataGrid(df)
        layout.addWidget(sheet1, 1, 0)
        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = Window()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**P.S..**
I am not a programmer, but a chemist trying to visualize some data.